# Copy file to iCloud without having to remove the local file

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

is there a way to copy a file (db. Sqlite) on iCloud without having to remove the local file?
I have got this code:

```
NSLog(@"File does not exist in cloud");
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
    NSURL *fromURL = [NSURL URLWithString:writableDBPath];
    BOOL success = [fileManager  setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:fromURL destinationURL:ubiquityURL error:&error];
    if (success)
    {
        NSLog(@"copied to icloud");
    }
```

The file is copied to iCloud but is removed from local but I also want you to stay locally. How it works?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:`.  Like so:

```
NSLog(@"File does not exist in cloud");
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
    NSURL *fromURL = [NSURL URLWithString:writableDBPath];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
           BOOL success =  [fileManager copyItemAtURL:fromURL toURL:ubiquityURL error:&error];
    if (success)
    {
        NSLog(@"copied to icloud");
    }
    });
```

Comment: unfortunately doesn't copy